# $this->load->model('model_name') vs $dboObj = new model_name();

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is there any advantage of using `$this->load->model('model_name')` instead of loading it using new operator like `$dboObj = new model_name();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very first time you do `$this->load->model('model_name')`, it will do a `require_once()` on that model (and `CI_Model`, `MY_Model`).

After that, no - there's no advantage to using it.

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference, but, Codeigniter's loaders require the file and assign an object:

```
$this->load->model('some_model','some');
$this->some->getAll();
```

There is a library that lets you use model as if it was laravel's active record:

[6 Codeigniter hacks](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/6-codeigniter-hacks-for-the-masters--net-8308)

```
$post = new Post();
$post->title = "Hello world";
$post->content = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet shalala";
$post->save();
```

You will need to add `require $file` sentence to include file, or extend Loader Class and make a global Model (MY_Model) that contains active record functions.